# Properly receive a nested object via post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send a complex object as a form object over to a mvc controller. However I just receive a `new` object with default values.

Here's the object (just a bit trimmed to make it simpler for the example)

```
public class AddProjectPopupModel
{
    public long SelectedCountryId;

    public Project ResultProject { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public long Number;

    public string Name;
}
```

And here's how I create the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProjectResult", "Popups", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addProjectForm"}))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResultProject.Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { Id = "number", Class = "validate", Value = 0 } })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ResultProject.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { Id = "name", Class = "validate" } })
}
```

Now I have a button which calls the following javascript:

```
var form = $("#addProjectForm");
var data = form.serialize();
var url = form.attr('action');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function(result) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

And the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProjectResult(AddProjectPopupModel model)
{
    return Json(new { Success = true });
}
```

I've also tried to change the controller parameters to:

```
public ActionResult AddProjectResult(long SelectedCountryId, Project ResultProject)
```

And here the `SelectedCountryId` gets filled properly, but not the Project.

I'd love to use the whole `AddProjectPopupModel` as parameter and not it's specific values.

However I can't figure out to do it properly.

Fiddler output for the call:

[image: ResultProject.Number=2&ResultProject.Name=awd&ResultProject.Location=awdawd&SelectedCountryId=2]

Debugger values in controller:

[image: SelectedCountryId: 2; ResultProject.Number: 0,...]

Comment: is that an `onClick` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in your project object you're using fileds

```
public class Project
{
    public long Number;

    public string Name;
}
```

and they should be properties so they can be navigated to

```
public class Project
{
    public long Number { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This should work

I recommend reading [Model Binding](https://mono.software/2017/02/09/model-binding-asp-net-mvc/) for more info